# AngularJS, save resource service json to localstorage and update conditionally

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ngresource

I need to update local-cached data by download large-size data from server only when new version detected, I am using `ngResource`,

```
goodServices.factory('Good', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('../WebService/list_goods.ashx?gid=:gid', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{q:'all'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

How to request and save the responded data to `LocalStorage` every time, when new version (GET a version number) detected.

Comment: You might have to create a wrapper service for that.

Comment: I separate two task into two services. one check and update, one read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for communicating with local storage I want to suggest [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) you can inject it in your controller

```
function yourBaseController(Good,$localStorage){
   var newVersion = Good.get(..your params), // it should return your new version
       currentVersion = $localStorage.version;
   if(newVersion !== currentVersion ){
      $localStorage.version = newVersion;
   }
}
```

Or if you don't have a base controller which is working at all time when your app bootstraps, you can move this logic in [.run](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) block

Comment: $localStorage is pretty nice, I found a little bug. setter for $localStorage like `$localStorage.data = data` seems to be asyn, and localStorage['ngStorage-data'] = data is sync.